# Spark job is stuck on method collect

Tags: apache-spark

When I run my Spark Job it appears to be stuck on collect :

[image]

I launch jar using command :

```
./spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.MyObject \
  --master spark://192.168.192.22:7077 \
  --executor-memory 512M \
  --driver-memory 512M \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --total-executor-cores 4 \
  /home/pi/spark-job-jars/spark-job-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Jar source : 

package com

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object MyObject {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("here")


    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())

    val l = (1 to 10).toList
    val s = sc.parallelize(l)
    val out = s.map(m => m * 3)
    out.collect.foreach(println)

  }

}
```

Jar pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>spark-job</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-job</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I can see job is running but never completes : 
[image]

Is there an issue with how I'm creating/deploying the jar so that it is unable to complete job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Alternatively, if your application is submitted from a machine far from the worker machines (e.g. locally on your laptop), it is common to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers and the executors. Note that cluster mode is currently not supported for standalone clusters, Mesos clusters, or python applications."

Taken from : 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

stop() the active SparkContext towards the end. That worked for me. For your code, try making this change.

```
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())

  try {

    val l = (1 to 10).toList
    val s = sc.parallelize(l)
    val out = s.map(m => m * 3)
    out.collect.foreach(println)

  } finally {
    sc.stop()
  }
```